# Generate points inside polygons in Python

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, rasterio, fiona

I have one raster image and one vector field. I cut the raster image according to the vector area. I want to get the coordinates of each pixel of the cut image, but I couldn't. While the expected results are in red, the result I get from Python is the points in purple. I think there may be a problem with the affine conversion after cropping the image is the reason for this shift.

**expected result**
[image]

**result from python**
[image]

```
for i in Path:
with fiona.open(i, "r") as shapefile:
  shapes = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]
with rasterio.open(j) as src:
    out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, shapes, crop=True,nodata=-32677,all_touched=False)
    height = out_image.shape[1]
    width =  out_image.shape[2]
    cols, rows = np.meshgrid(np.arange(width), np.arange(height))
    xs, ys = rasterio.transform.xy(out_transform, rows, cols)
    lons = np.array(xs)
    lats = np.array(ys)
    points = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(list(zip(lons.flatten(), lats.flatten())))
    geoms = points.values
```

Comment: Well by gridding the entire height and width of the masked subset you're filling the entire bounding box of the AOI with points.  So just intersect the resulting points with the original polygon

Comment: As for the slight rotation, are you sure your GIS software isn't reprojecting on the fly?  In ArcMap, for example, make sure the dataframe is set to the same projection as the data

Comment: You say "want to get the coordinates of each pixel of the cut image" but the red points are not all pixels in the raster image of the field you are showing. You have clipped another raster that you are not showing?